# Fast way to combine multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've tried an sql-query like this:

```
SELECT A.id, FROM_UNIXTIME(A.timestamp) AS timestamp, A.test, B.test2, B.test3, C.test4
FROM table AS A
INNER JOIN table  AS B
        ON A.id = B.id - 3
INNER JOIN table  AS C
        ON A.id = C.id - 6
ORDER BY id DESC
```

To merge different rows from one table together.

But it is very slow. Is there an way to speed it up in MySQL itself. I want to create an view to select the data from tableau (tableau itself has no preprocessing).

With an postprocessing script it would be very easy (just save up to six old columns and read it back six rows later). Shouldn't such an easy task possible with SQL too?

---

Example:

**Original Table**

| id | timestamp | test | test2 | test3 | test4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | … | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | … | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | … | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | … | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | … | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | … | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | … | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 8 | … | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 9 | … | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| 10 | … | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 11 | … | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 12 | … | 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 13 | … | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |

**Needed result:**

| id | timestamp | test | test2 | test3 | test4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | … | 1 | null | null | null |
| 2 | … | 2 | null | null | null |
| 3 | … | 3 | null | null | null |
| 4 | … | 4 | 1 | 1 | null |
| 5 | … | 5 | 2 | 2 | null |
| 6 | … | 6 | 3 | 3 | null |
| 7 | … | 7 | 4 | 4 | null |
| 8 | … | 8 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 9 | … | 9 | 6 | 6 | 2 |
| 10 | … | 10 | 7 | 7 | 3 |
| 11 | … | 11 | 8 | 8 | 4 |
| 12 | … | 12 | 9 | 9 | 5 |
| 13 | … | 13 | 10 | 10 | 6 |

ID is an unique autoincrement value.

Comment: "Very slow" means what? Why are you subtracting from an `id` column? What is this even doing? What's easy in SQL is not necessarily easy in application code, and the same goes for the reverse. If this is quick application side, you have a solution.

Comment: Note: `id` values *might* be issued sequentially, or there might be gaps. `id - 3` is an extremely unreliable way to get "three rows earlier".

Comment: Slow means: If I use Limit (for example 0,100) only it runs in the 30sec timout.
With an external script and reading the data without the joins (and do the task by the script) it needs only a few millisecs.

I added an example to the first post.

Comment: How many rows does this table have? How many in the result set? It's worth noting this approach is going to be very inefficient since it necessarily duplicates data in the results. This looks much more easily accommodated application-side.

Comment: At the moment I think 5Mio Rows. It's an plain measurement storage from an machine from different stations. Each row is currently one cycle of the machine. But I want to get an row per part. Thats the reason I need the "shift". From the machine side there is no possibility to preprocess the data.

Hmm, actually I want to avoid an preprocessing between the database and tableau.

Comment: If it's that many rows then doing this SQL-side will be ugly. Just do it in the application layer. There's no need to increase the data five-fold just to get the results exactly as you want, at the expense of an ugly, expensive, probably unreliable query.

Comment: If the data is relatively static consider using a materialized `VIEW` so you can pay that expense once, then use the same result set over and over cheaply.

Comment: I forgot: Out of this 5Mio pool I query only a few thousands at once. Hmm, maybe you're right an extra application layer would be better. The data is static but the requested time range changes. My other ideas was to use procedures to write the data to a temporary table and "shift" it on this (small) table. But at the moment I have no experiences with procedures. So i don't know if the idea is good.